# Prove this set is closed

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the following set is convex, closed and bounded:

$$\left\{x: x=(x_{1},\dots , x_{n}) \land (\forall i, x_{i}\geq0) \land \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=1\right\}.$$

I've been able to prove it is convex and bounded, but I can't seem to use its compliment to show that the compliment is open. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Define $f: \mathbb{R}_+^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f:(x_1,...x_n) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}$

Is $f$ continuous ?

Then try to write this set as $f^{-1}(F)$ where $F$ is a closed set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't seem to able to access that account, so please excuse me for using a new account. Is this correct then?

*Thank you for the hints. Hence, is it:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}= \sum_{1}^{n} x_{i} $

Define $A=\left\{x: x=(x_{1},\dots , x_{n}) \land (\forall i, x_{i}\geq0) \land \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=1\right\}.$

$f(A) = \{1\} $

$\{1\}$ is closed because it is a singleton.

$f(•)$ is continuous because it is linear.

Hence, $f^{-1} (1)$ is closed.

*adding from hint below*
$A= f^{-1} (1) \cap \{x=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}) | x_{i} \geq 0 \forall i\} $

Hence now I need to prove 
$B = \{x=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}) | x_{i} \geq 0 \forall i\} $ is closed.

Do I prove that $B^{c} = \{x=(x_{1},\dots,x_{n}) | x_{i} < 0 \exists i\} $ is open?

----- edit ----

OR

If I change the mapping to $f: \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, does $f^{-1} (1)= A$?

Comment: So far so good, but $f^{-1}(1)$ is not $A$ (it is not limited to points with positive coordinates). But what can you say about $f^{-1}(1) \cap \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n : x_i \geq 0\ \forall i\}$?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Thanks to the hints I know that $f^{-1} (-1)$ is closed, and I do realise I need to show that the intersection of the two sets you mention are closed to show $A$ is closed. I can tell intuitively that the second set is closed, but I'm also having problems showing it mathematically.

Comment: Yes, showing that $B^c$ is open is a good way. I wrote a proof of this as an answer since it was too long for a comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. It has helped tremendously. I do realise this isn't very difficult but I am a beginner in set theory so please excuse my lack of knowledge. Are there any books you could recommend so I could improve myself?

Comment: For a good introductory real analysis book, you might consider Abbott's [Understanding Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Understanding-Analysis-Undergraduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/1493927116)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the notation used by the OP in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1845393/169852) (which is really a continuation of the question):

Yes, it's probably easiest to prove that $B^c$ is open, where
$$B = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n : x_i \geq 0\ \forall i\}$$

Suppose $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in B^c$. We wish to show that there is some $\epsilon$-ball, centered at $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, which is contained in $B^c$.

Since $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in B^c$, there is some $i$ such that $x_i < 0$. Choose any $\epsilon$ satisfying $0 < \epsilon < |x_i| = -x_i$. Let $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$ be any point within the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}(x_k - y_k)^2 < \epsilon^2$, and consequently $(x_i - y_i)^2 < \epsilon^2$. Taking square roots, we obtain $|x_i - y_i| < \epsilon < |x_i| = -x_i$.

This means that
$$y_i = (y_i - x_i) + x_i \leq |y_i - x_i| + x_i < -x_i + x_i = 0$$
which shows that $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n) \in B^c$, so $B^c$ is open, and therefore $B$ is closed.

---

Now we can finish the argument. As you noted, the function 
$f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$
defined by $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n$ is continuous, and $\{1\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$, so $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n : \sum x_i = 1\}$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^n$.

Then $\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n : \sum x_i = 1 \text{ and }x_i \geq 0\ \forall i\} = f^{-1}(\{1\}) \cap B$ is the intersection of two closed subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, so it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Hint, use the first hint and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorff then the set {1} is closed, so the preimage  $f^{-1}({1})$ of a closed set is closed.
Remains to show that f is continuous.
f is continuous because it is linear and $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are finite-dimensional normed linear spaces.